# What is his mark Vs. What mark does he have (school mark)

Tags: questions

Well, the question is in the title. I should translate one phrase and I don't know the right answer. What is his mark? or What mark does he have? Which one is correct? What the difference between them?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What kind of mark?

Comment: I mean a school mark (a grade).

Comment: What mark _did he get_?

Comment: Note that in some countries (United States I think, and maybe others), the term used is "grade". I only ever heard my grandmother talk about "good marks".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of them are wrong; in fact, they're used interchangeably in school settings. However, there is a difference between them.

> What is his mark in Science?
>   *His mark is an 84 [percent]*.

The mark has a value. This question is simply asking what that value is. *His mark* is the subject.

> What mark does he have in Science? *He has an 84 [percent].*

He has a certain mark. This question demands the same answer as the previous one, but it's phrased in a less direct fashion, instead asking for specifications on something he has. *He* is the subject. In conversations between students, this is probably the most common.

An example brought up in the comments was

> What mark did he get? *He got an 84 [percent].*

This is different from the other two because it implies that the mark was given at an earlier time, while the others ask for the mark at the current time.